# A riddle: "With a heart of ice, / The height of a tree..."

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

An above-average hard riddle (no rhymes, though):

> With a heart of ice,
> The height of a tree.
> Not to be cryptic,
> Easily found when changing.
> The C to a D.
> What am I?

What is the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you a

> YETI or Abominable Snowman?

This fits best to the lines about

> not cryptic but changing the C to a D: this creature is a [cryptid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cryptids).

It could be the height of a tree, as

> [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeti) some varieties can grow up to 15 feet tall,

and the "heart of ice" could mean either

> that it lives in icy country

or a wordplayish reference to

> the [Yeti ice chest](https://www.yeti.com/en_US/coolers/hard-coolers).